# Create device nodes from initramfs on embedded Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, embedded, embedded-linux, mount

Linux v2.6.26.5 embedded on device, Squashfs on NAND flash chip. I need mount the root filesystem from busybox shell (initramfs). The old Linux kernel missing fs driver for automatic setup of `/dev`, not using devtmpfs, so I need to create the basic device nodes manually use **mknod** (/dev/null, /dev/zero, dev/mtdblock4, ttys). What is correct steps to setup and mount root from a busybox shell based on given details?

Kernel has been loaded, file system have the following structure:

```
BusyBox v1.10.2 (2017-08-02 14:07:25 CST) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

/bin/sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
# mount -t proc proc /proc
# mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys
# ls -l
drwxrwxr-x    2 1005     1005          432 Aug  2  2017 bin
-rwxr-xr-x    1 1005     1005       715844 Aug  2  2017 cordless_nodect.coma
drwxr-xr-x    2 0        0              32 Aug  2  2017 dev
drwxr-xr-x    2 1005     1005            3 Aug  2  2017 eeprom
drwxr-xr-x    4 1005     1005          386 Aug  2  2017 etc
drwxr-xr-x    2 1005     1005            3 Aug  2  2017 fpar
drwxr-xr-x    4 0        0              48 Aug  2  2017 home
drwxr-xr-x    2 1005     1005            3 Aug  2  2017 hsfw
drwxr-xr-x    3 1005     1005          287 Aug  2  2017 lib
drwxrwxr-x    2 1005     1005            3 Aug  2  2017 mnt
drwxr-xr-x    2 1005     1005            3 Aug  2  2017 nvram
dr-xr-xr-x   27 0        0               0 Jan  1 00:00 proc
lrwxrwxrwx    1 1005     1005            8 Aug  2  2017 root -> tmp/root
drwxr-xr-x    2 1005     1005          642 Aug  2  2017 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   10 0        0               0 Jan  1 00:00 sys
drwxr-xr-x    2 1005     1005            3 Aug  2  2017 tmp
drwxr-xr-x    7 1005     1005           73 Aug  2  2017 usr
lrwxrwxrwx    1 1005     1005            7 Aug  2  2017 var -> tmp/var
drwxr-xr-x    6 1005     1005         4051 Aug  2  2017 www

# mount -t devtmpfs devtmpfs /dev
mount: mounting devtmpfs on /dev failed: No such device
# mount /dev/mtd4 /mnt/root
mount: mounting /dev/mtd4 on /mnt/root failed: No such file or directory
# cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

  31     0        384 mtdblock0
  31     1        128 mtdblock1
  31     2      20352 mtdblock2
  31     3       7168 mtdblock3
  31     4      18816 mtdblock4
  31     5       2048 mtdblock5
  31     6       1024 mtdblock6
  31     7        512 mtdblock7
  31     8        128 mtdblock8
  31     9        512 mtdblock9
  31    10        512 mtdblock10
# cat /proc/filesystems
nodev   sysfs
nodev   rootfs
nodev   bdev
nodev   proc
nodev   debugfs
nodev   sockfs
nodev   pipefs
nodev   anon_inodefs
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   inotifyfs
nodev   configfs
nodev   devpts
    squashfs
nodev   ramfs
nodev   nfs
nodev   jffs2
nodev   mqueue
nodev   rpc_pipefs
# cat /proc/devices
Character devices:
  1 mem
  2 pty
  3 ttyp
  4 /dev/vc/0
  4 tty
  4 ttyS
  5 /dev/tty
  5 /dev/console
  5 /dev/ptmx
  7 vcs
 10 misc
 13 input
 89 i2c
 90 mtd
108 ppp
128 ptm
136 pts
153 spi
204 ttyJ
254 cordless

Block devices:
  1 ramdisk
 31 mtdblock
 93 nftl
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify fstab file. An step by step example of how to create fstab file from scratch and fill entries to mount is [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/clfs/view/clfs-3.0/x86/bootable/fstab.html).